# test class on lead where through an error if email entered is already exists contacts

Tags: unit-test, class

Apex Class:

```
public class Handler_checkiftheemail {
    public static void TriggerHAndler(List<Lead> newLeadList){
        List<string> LE=new List<string>();
        for(Lead La:newLeadList){
            if(La.Email !=Null){
                LE.add(La.Email);
            }
        }
        List<Contact> Conlist=[select id,Email from contact where Email IN:LE];
        list<string> conEmail=new list<string>();
        for(Contact Con:Conlist){
            conEmail.add(Con.Email);
        }
        for(Lead La:newLeadList){
            if(conEmail.contains(La.Email)){
                La.addError('Email entered is already existing in contact');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

//// The above is my handler ////

```
@istest
public class Test_Handler_checkiftheemail {
  private static testmethod void testclass(){  
    list<Lead> Lelist=new list<Lead>();
    list<Contact> conList=new list<Contact>();
    Contact Con=new Contact();
    Con.LastName='lastname';
    Con.Email='test@email.com';
    Conlist.add(Con);
    insert Conlist;
    
    Lead Le = new Lead();
    Le.LastName ='lastname';
    Le.Status ='Open - Not Contacted';
    Le.Company='testcompany';
    Le.Email='test@email.com';
   
    Lelist.add(Le);
    List<Database.SaveResult> saveResults = Database.insert(Lelist);
    for (Integer intCount = 0; intCount < saveResults.size(); intCount++) {
        List<Database.Error> errors = saveResults.get(0).errors;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any error in this? What is the question?

Comment: hy @NagendraSingh here am trying to write a test class i need to make the code coverage of 100% on the above scenario how do i achieve that  and i didn't understand how to cover the error message in the test class

Answer (score 0):

Remove the if condition:

```
if(Con.Email != Le.Email){
   insert Lelist;
}
```

You are trying to create a scenario where if you email already exists in contact then you should throw an error. Now if you add this condition then it never inserts a lead as your contact email and lead email is same.

Remove the if condition and insert lead via `Database.insert` method. Take the `Database.SaveResult` return type and assert the error message.
For eg:

```
List<Database.SaveResult> saveResults = Database.insert(Lelist);
for (Integer intCount = 0; intCount < saveResults.size(); intCount++) {
    List<Database.Error> errors = saveResults.get(0).errors;
    //Check if error is not empty and then check if error message has the same message as you trigger
}
```

Comment: hy @Nagedra Singh it was not so helpful could you please recheck it...

Comment: Share your updated code once. This should have covered it.

Comment: Dont edit my answer, update your question and share updated code

Comment: ok then i will update my code in the above